# Is it possible to change gridviewid to to a gridview DataSouce after the gridview is loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Is it possible to change a gridviews `DataSouceId`  to a gridview DataSouce after the gridview is loaded. I have a gridview with a `DataSouceId` that is equal to `SqlDatasource`. I have a button when pressed executes a some LINQ which I want to change what's in the gridview.

```
       var sce = from pk in db.Tables
                 where pk.Score > 20
                 select new { pk.First_Name, pk.Last_Name, pk.Score };

    GridView1.DataSourceID = "";
    GridView1.DataSource = sce;
    GridView1.DataBind();


    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="First Name" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="First Name" HeaderText="First Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="First Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Last Name" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="Last Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Score" HeaderText="Score" SortExpression="Score" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nationality" HeaderText="Nationality" SortExpression="Nationality" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I tried to change to a empty string. This compiles but crashes when the button is clicked.

Is what I'm trying possible?

Comment: Crashes with what error?

Comment: http exception was unhandled by user code                                              DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType0`3[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' does not contain a property with the name 'First Name'.

Comment: Can you show your GridView markup, including columns?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the query defines columns with different names from what the GridView expects. For example, compare:

```
pk.First_Name
```

and

```
DataField="First Name"
```

These are different, theerefore GridView is not able to find the column in data source and throws exception.

The best option would be to use underscore in GridView as well. That might require some refactoring in your initial SQL, but it should e done anyway - having spaces in column names is very brittle and uncommon, better refrain from it altogether:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="First_Name" ...
```

Or you can define a `TemplateField` that looks for column with either name and displays what was found. But that sounds like a terribly huge overhead.